# the state of ASLR, PIE, SSP on Debian in 2018?

Tags: hardening, aslr, debian, gcc

As far as I remember, 
most Debian Wheezy packages were not compiled with those useful security flags (ASLR, PIE, SSP, and more).

Did the situation improve with Debian Squeeze or the upcoming Debian Buster ?

By comparison, Ubuntu and Fedora have a nice *security features matrix*, but I couldnt find a clear answer for Debian.

- Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features
- Fedora: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Security_Features_Matrix

Comment: Have you tried using [checksec](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh)? And here is the [2014 status](https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2014/02/03/compiler-hardening-in-ubuntu-and-debian/).

Answer (score 2):

you can check if a binary is compiled with

1. PIE
2. stack protection
3. fortify source
4. RO relocations
5. Immediate binding

by using `hardening-check`. E.g. `hardening-check $(which sshd)`
Package `devscripts` contains the `hardening-check`

On Debian testing i get the following output:

```
root@root:~# hardening-check $(which sshd)
/usr/sbin/sshd
Position Independent Executable: yes
Stack protected: yes
Fortify Source functions: yes (some protected funcions found)
Read-only relocations: yes
Immediate binding: yes
```

[See the following answer on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89214)